# PHP Jqgrid code doesnt work

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I tried to replicate the code here http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/phpintegration/bind-jquery-grid-to-mysql-database-using-php.htm
but can't get my code to work .Here is the html

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jqx.classic.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqxmenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqxdata.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqxgrid.js"></script>
    <script>$(document).ready(function () {
    // prepare the data
    var source ={
        datatype: "json",
        datafields: [{ name: 'a' },{ name: 's'},],
        url: 'data.php'
    };
    $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
        source: source,
        theme: 'classic',
        columns: [{ text: 'a', datafield: 'a', width: 250 },{ text: 's', datafield: 's', width: 150}]
    });
     });</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="jqxgrid"></div>
</body>
```

Here is the php file data.php

```
<?php
#Include the connect.php file
include("connect.php");
// Connect to the database
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
    }
// get data and store in a json array
$from = 0;
$to = 30;
$query = "SELECT a,s from test LIMIT ?,?";
$result = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$result->bind_param('ii', $from, $to);
$result->execute();
/* bind result variables */
$result->bind_result($a,$s);
/* fetch values */
while ($result->fetch())
    {
    $t[] = array(
        'a' => $a,
        's' => $s
    );
    }
echo json_encode($t);
/* close statement */
$result->close();
/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You use wrong tag of the question: you should change "jqgrid" tag to "jqxgrid".

Comment: for now I see a blank webpage, I did'nt realize that I was using jqxgrid I will  attempt to write the code with jqgrid instead

Comment: Can you please suggest a good tutorial for Jqgrid with select and update using php